# Grafana alerting even though metric is fine

Tags: grafana

We want an alert, when there is any logback-error (`count > 0`). But we get an alert even though the count is 0.

TestRule shows `value 3`, but the actual metric is 0:

[image]

The Rule is configured like this:
[image]

As you can see in the first screenshot, the metric is alerting (red-background of the panel), but the metric is 0. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count()` should be replaced by `sum()` in the rule condition.